# Prioritize boxes inside flexbox

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have three `div`s inside a flexbox. I want them to appear inline. But if there is to much text in the first div, I want to truncate this text to make sure I always can see the text of the second and third `div`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-1 item">
   !!!Scale me down If I am too big for the screen!!! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="flex-2 item">Always show me. Dont let flex-1 push me outside</div>
  <div class="flex-3 item">Always show me. Dont let flex-1 push me outside</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 5em;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 1 1 5em;
}

.flex-3 {
  flex: 1 1 5em;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMmGGz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend use Sass/Scss to use DRY principle. Use mixin

**Scss**

```
@mixin trunc-text {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and in your classes

```
 @for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .flex-#{$i} { 
    @include trunc-text;
      @if $i == 1 {
        flex: 5 1 5rem
      } @else {
        flex: 1 1 5rem;
      }
  }
}
```

This at the beggining might frightening you, but it's quite powerful.

The output in **Css**

```
.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 1 1 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.flex-3 {
  flex: 1 1 5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```